# Is there a way to find out the maximum memory of a database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm writing a Web Application in Oracle Apex. Is there any table where I can find out the maximum usable memory? It needs to be an SQL Statement.

I've searched on google but I found not the right answer for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Oracle memory is arranged into two chunks:

1. The Shared Global Area
2. The Program Global Area

These chunks are subdivided to support different types of database operations. The documentation covers all this in greater detail. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/memory.htm#CNCPT007)

For your specific purpose, the maximum size of the SGA and PGA will give you the *"maximum usable memory"*. This query provides that information:

```
select name, value
from   v$parameter
where  name in ('sga_max_size', 'pga_aggregate_limit')
```

For these parameters `value` is in bytes. You may wish to sum them together, but the two areas are not fungible so it's probably more useful to know the two allocations.

Note that `v$parameter` is not exposed to non-DBA users by default. So you may need to get privileges granted to your user before you can build an Apex screen over it.